# Liferay 7.1 OpenID Connect as default login

Tags: wso2, liferay, single-sign-on, openid-connect

Recently I migrated from 7.0 GA5 to 7.1 GA1 and I have a SSO configuration with WSO2 using OpenID Connect.

Is it possible to skip the default login page and be automatically redirected to WSO2 login without clicking on "OpenID Connect" and the provider choice? (Like it was in the 7.0 with OIDC Plugin)

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution this this?

Comment: Yes, I've adapted the plugin for OpenID Connect of Liferay 7.0 for Liferay 7. 1

Comment: I found another solution. I'll add it to this post shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this simply by adding a portal-ext.properties setting

```
auth.login.url=/home/-/login/openid_connect_request?p_p_state=maximized&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_saveLastPath=false&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_redirect=/&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_OPEN_ID_CONNECT_PROVIDER_NAME=WSO2
```

Doing this then takes users directly to the OpenID Connect providers sign in page if they try and sign in.

Comment: I've tested this on Liferay 7.2 (not 7.1)